# How to get a Response from other web site, using Jquery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, http-response-codes

I have a query

I need to make a login form, where I have to get a Response from other web site, i know there is HttpResponseMessage, but I think this is to consume a web API, so I really wanna know how to get the response of the web site, cause I need to get a success login or if there is a fail with the logon

Is there any ways to make it?

and the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSub").click(function(){
    if($("#User").val() == "" || $("#Pass").val() == ""){
     alert("Insert User & Password");
     event.preventDefault();
    }else{
     $("#LogBox").hide();
    }
    
   }); 
  });
 
 </script>

<section class="container">
     <div class="login">
      <h1>Inicio de Sesión</h1>
      <form action="http://us.mzoneweb.net/Scope.MZone.Web/Logon.ashx" method="post" target="TheMZoneFrame">
       <p><input name="Username" id="User" type="text" placeholder="Usuario"></p>
       <p><input name="Password" id="Pass" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"></p>
       <p><input name="LogoutUrl" type="hidden" value=""></p>
       <p><input name="ErrorUrl" type="hidden" value=""></p>
       <p><input name="Version" type="hidden" value=""></p>
            
       <p class="remember_me">
       <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
       Remember me on this computer
       </label>
       </p>
       <p class="submit"><input name="Submit1" id="btnSub" type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" ></p>
      </form>
     </div>
    </section>


<iframe src="" height="100%" id="TheMZoneFrame" name="TheMZoneFrame" width="100%" frameborder="0">
 <noframes>Your browser does not support IFRAME elements.</noframes>
 </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Here's a sample function that will get a response from another site:

```
/*
 * Makes an HTTP request via GET or POST, and can download a file
 * @returns - Returns the response of the request
 * @param $url - The URL to request, including any GET parameters
 * @param $params - An array of POST values to send
 * @param $filename - If provided, the response will be saved to the 
 *    specified filename
 */
function request($url, $params = array(), $filename = "") {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlOpts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        // Set Useragent
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) 
                    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
        // Don't validate SSL 
        // This is to prevent possible errors with self-signed certs
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    );
    if(!empty($filename)){
        // If $filename exists, save content to file
        $file2 = fopen($filename,'w+') 
            or die("Error[".__FILE__.":".__LINE__."] 
                    Could not open file: $filename");
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_FILE] = $file2;
    }
    if (!empty($params)) {
        // If POST values are given, send that shit too
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    // If there was an error, show it
    if (curl_error($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    if(!empty($filename)) fclose($file2);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: @ÁngelAnguianoRamirez - If this helps please hit the checkmark by my answer and you'll get your first 2 points. You can upvote if you like it too. Thanks!